# How to solve this output [object Object] for an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to Pass an array of Objects through a map function, but when trying to obtain those Objects, I am receiving **`[object Object]`** as output.
The data I am passing is

```
const Data =[
    {
   "Date":"Thu Jul 06 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"9 seats available",
  
  },
  {
   "Date":"Fri Jul 07 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"7 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sat Jul 08 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"10 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sun Jul 09 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"3 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Mon Jul 10 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"14 seats available",
  },
  
  {
   "Date":"Wed Jul 12 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty": "12 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Thu Jul 13 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty": "15 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Fri Jul 14 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"8 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sat Jul 15 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"1 seats available"
  } 
  ]
```

The map function I am passing it to

```
      {Data.map((d, i) => {
          return (
           <div key={i} >
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td className="date">{d.Date}</td>
        <td className="time">{d.Time}</td>
        <td className="availability" >{d.Availabilty}</td>
        {console.log(d)}
        <td><button value={d} onClick={(e)=>{
          decNum(e);
          }}>Book Now</button></td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

When I am trying to get the values through onclick event, I am getting the mentioned `[object Object]` output.
I am able to get the values as `d.Date or D.Time or D.Availabilty`
But what i want is to get the result for d and not a particular key.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not think HTML supports objects as values or for any attribute for that matter. What you can do is `JSON.stringify(d)` and inside the `onClick` you can parse the value as a JSON object using `JSON.parse(value)`.

Comment: I don't know what `decNum` function is, but you are passing it the click event, not `d`. Try `onClick={()=>{decNum(d);}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{Data.map((d) => {
  const {Date: date, Time, Availabilty} = d;
  return (
   <div key={`${date}${Time}${Availabilty}`}>
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td className="date">{date}</td>
          <td className="time">{Time}</td>
          <td className="availability" >{Availabilty}</td>
          <td><button value={d} onClick={decNum}>Book Now</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```